# Difference of two pseudodifferential operators of the same order

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, pseudo-differential-operators

Let $M$ be a manifold. Does there exist a theorem that says something like: "given two pseudodifferential operators $P$ and $Q$ on $M$ of the same order $k$, there exists an $L^2$-bounded operator $B$ such that $P-BQ$ has order at most $k-1$?"

I feel like this should be true, but do not know of a proof/reference. Any help finding either would be appreciated.

Comment: I very much doubt that. Have you considered $P=d/dx$ and $Q=x d/dx$ on $\mathbb{R}$ (or $S^1$ if you want your manifold compact)? I'd assume that  because $Q$ is $0$ at the origin, any $B$ satisfying your condition would have to be too singular to be $L^2$-bounded.

Comment: I see...what I'm trying to understand is if one defines the $k$-th Sobolev norm by $||u||_{H^k(M)}:=\sum_{i=0}^k\langle D^i u,D^i u\rangle_{L^2(M)}$, where $D$ is a PDO of order $1$ and $u\in C_c(M)$, then does every PDO $P$ of order $k$ extend to a bounded operator $H^k(M)\rightarrow H^0(M)$? I cannot seem to find a straightforward reference for this in the non-compact setting. Of course, it seems by your example that the argument I'm thinking of wouldn't work either in the compact setting...

Comment: In that generality you cannot expect boundedness, it even fails for $k=0$. There are many $0$th order operators on a (non-compact) manifolds which are not $L^2$-bounded, think of the operator that multiplies with an unbounded function.

Comment: Also, for your definition of the Sobolev-norm: Even on compact manifolds you have to make sure that $D$ is elliptic in order to get back the usual Sobolev spaces. In general the completion of say $C_c^\infty$ with respect to that norm is very hard to understand.

Comment: Thanks, I see. What I'm most interested in is the properly supported elliptic case (and, more generally, properly supported operators $P$ for which $\limsup_{\xi\rightarrow\infty}||\sigma_P(x,\xi)||<C$ in some global fashion on $M$). Two questions would be: 1. Do any two such $P$ define the same Sobolev spaces? 2. If $P$ and $Q$ are two such operators, does there exist an order $0$, $L^2$-bounded operator $B$ such that $P-BQ$ has order at most $k-1$?

Comment: Assuming that we are in the non-compact case, (1) cannot be true: Again take $\mathbb{R}$ and let $P$ and $Q$ be multiplication operators by functions which vanish to a different degree at $\infty$. Then the "Sobolev spaces" are weighted $L^2$-spaces which don't coincide if the weights are not comparable. For (2) you could first take a parametrix  $R$ of $Q$,  then $RQ = I - K$, where $K$ is smoothing. Then $P- (PR)Q = PK$ is smoothing as well. If you want to have this $L^2$-bounded you need control on the parametrix, i.e. in particular control on the inverse of $\sigma_Q$.

Comment: (In hindsight my counterexample does not quite fit, because you wanted $1$st order operators. But on $\mathbb{R}$, first taking derivatives and then multiplying by non comparable weights should do the trick.)